# Is it possible to derive the angular frequency of a simple harmonic oscillator using total energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

> I want to show that 
>   $$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$
>   using the fact that
>   $$E=K+U=\frac{1}{2}mv_x^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2=\frac{1}{2}kA^2.$$

The issue is that I have derived a formula that isn't correct:

I first took the time derivative of the energy equation,

$\dfrac{dE}{dt}=mv_x\dfrac{dv_x}{dt}+kx\dfrac{dx}{dt}=kA\dfrac{dA}{dt}$

$\dfrac{dE}{dt}=mv_xa_x+kxv_x=kAv_x$.

So we now have

$mv_xa_x+kxv_x=kAv_x$

$ma_x+kx=kA$

Substituting $a_x=-\omega^2x$ gives

$-m\omega^2x+kx=kA$

$m\omega^2x=k(x-A)$

$\omega^2=\dfrac{k}{m}\dfrac{(x-A)}{x}$

$\omega=\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{m}\dfrac{(x-A)}{x}}$.

This is very nearly correct but not quite...

Is it possible to prove this formula in this way? Also, if I haven't done something that's completely incorrect, then is this a standard formulae that I just haven't seen before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to prove something, you need to get your hypotheses straight. I understand that you want to prove that a mass $m$ on a spring with constant $k$ moves harmonically with frequency $\sqrt{k/m}$, but you seem to be assuming that result in your "proof":

First off, writing $E = \frac12 k A^2$ already implies that the motion is harmonic with frequency $\sqrt{k/m}$, partly because you need to know $x(t)$ and $\dot{x}(t)$ to plug into $E$, but also because $A$ is the amplitude, a notion which doesn't make sense if the motion isn't harmonic!

Also, $dA/dt$ isn't $v$ (because $dx/dt$ is $v$), it's zero: the amplitude is a constant. Using that you can get the equation of motion, but there's that same problem again: stating that $\ddot{x} = -\omega^2 x$ already assumes that $x$ is a simple harmonic motion.

The way to prove what you want is to guess a solution of the form $x=\cos(\omega t)$ (you could also use $\sin(\omega t)$) and plug it either into the energy (and then demand that the energy be a constant, that is, $dE/dt = 0$), or into the equation of motion $\ddot{x} + \frac{k}{m}x =0$. You will find that for the equations to be satisfied, it must be that $\omega^2 = \frac{k}{m}$.

Answer (score 2):

Energy is conserved in a simple harmonic oscillator, so $dE/dt = 0$.  From there you can get the angular frequency by your same logic.

Another way of seeing this: A is a constant of the motion, so its time derivative is 0.